# unknown field error don't know where it is , django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s)

Tags: python, django

```
class ManageKnowledgeProductTrainingType(models.Model):
    training_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False,default='', verbose_name="Training Type")
    product  = models.ForeignKey(ManageProductName, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True, verbose_name="Product")
    nature_of_training = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False,default='', verbose_name="Nature of Training")
    training_name  = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False,default='', verbose_name="Training Name")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, default='', verbose_name="Title")
    purpose  = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False,default='', verbose_name="Purpose of Training")
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Start Date")
    upload_documents = models.FileField(upload_to='product_training/%Y/%m/%d/',null=True, verbose_name="Upload Documents")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=1, verbose_name="Is Active")
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.training_type

    class Meta:
        db_table = "manage_knowledge_product_training_type"
        unique_together= ('training_type', 'product', 'nature_of_training', 'training_name')
```

**django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (chapter) specified for ManageKnowledgeProductTrainingType**

Comment: maybe error in migrations. Can you show migrations data of ManageKnowledgeProductTrainingType? Its appear in folder `migrations`. Or in Form you use model

Comment: thank you for you time , I got the solution ,it was my mistake that i mistakely remove field. field exit in db but not in model.py